# Publishing electron app to release section in github.com gives unwanted prompt when user tries to install it on Mac OS

Tags: macos, github, electron, publish

I have project that builds electron package for MacOS.
Ive followed this tutorial.
https://www.electron.build/code-signing
I did it all and published it as release on github.
Everything worked as expected but when i download it to my computer i still get message that i have to approve application
It gives me this prompt

> “MyApp” is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want
> to open it?

I want to continue to publish my app to releases section on github.com
Is there any way i can sign my pacakge in a way that github.com will be ok to install on user computer?
Thanks

Comment: Alex, I'm pretty sure the "downloaded from the internet...." warning can NOT BE AVOIDED in MacOS ... it's a nuisance for sure.  Maybe someone has more info.

Comment: Have you notarized your application as well?

Comment: That looks like the usual warning given for tons of other apps too

Comment: Yes. I guess ill have to live with it. Thanks for all the answers.